# Suitable Collection class for Sorted Data requiring fast retrieval

Tags: c#, collections

I am working in a scenario where I need to store a collection of `KeyValuePair`, having a `DateTimeOffset` as key.
I am receiving a list of this data (via Http request) which I simply need to read and generate the collection from. It is required that the collection be maintained sorted, and it must be enumerable. Also, I may need to do a lot of lookups on this data by key.

Also note that the data I receive is already sorted in itself. I may repeat the operation of receiving data and generating the collection again, periodically. However, the existing collection is not modified, rather a new one is created each time I refresh the data.

Now, I have these methods in mind:

1. Use a `SortedDictionary<,>` (My current method).
2. Use a `Dictionary<,>` which is manually sorted after populating all items from the received data. (While this makes it very fast to look-up (O(1)), I need to now sort the data, since a `Dictionary<,>` does not maintain its items when added in an ordered manner.)
3. Use a simple array (or `List`) which is directly populated from the data. The order of elements is maintained implicitly. Then, searching for items (i.e. look-ups) are done using Binary Search upon the keys.

Which method is appropriate for this scenario? Are there any other options or variations to the above methods I can use which will give me better overall performance?

**Edit**

I'm sorry, I've forgotten to mention that I am developing for the WinRT (specifically Windows Phone) platform. Hence I cannot use `SortedList<,>`(nor `OrderedDictionary`), which would have been the best choice as pointed out by @lc.

Also, my collection will only have a few 100 items. Perhaps at this scale there may not be any significant difference, but I'd like to know an answer all the same.

Comment: Let's assume that there exists a data structure that does what you want. Can you elaborate on the specifics of the questions you want to pose this data structure as well as what kind of answer you want? For instance, do you need to access it by index? Do you need to output it sorted as a whole? Is it only sorted on the way in? What if you combined a list for index+sorted access and a dictionary for direct key lookups, would that work?

Comment: Looking quickly at MSDN, a `SortedList<,>` is in fact probably what you're after. In particular, look at the Remarks section of https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132319%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Depends upon what you do the most you can choose your data structure. If you lookup mostly and modify the collection rarely -- you need a collection which performs better in lookups. And so forth. [This may help](http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2011/06/16/c.net-fundamentals-choosing-the-right-collection-class.aspx)

Comment: @Lasse I will need to output it as a whole. Also, it is never manipulated. On a refresh, a fresh collection is prepared and the old one is discarded.

Comment: @Ic Please see the edit for the question, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Of the three options, I would certainly exclude 1 (`SortedDictionary`) because 3 (array or `List`) outperforms it given your requirements (fast lookups, sorted, items provided in order, not modified).

Doing binary search on a sorted array runs in O(lg n) time. According to the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7fta44c%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), look-ups in `SortedDictionary` also run in O(lg n) time, so no advantage in using it.

Since the data you get is already sorted, then the array is populated in O(n). Insertion in `SortedDictionary` runs in O(lg n) so populating it runs in O(n * lg n), which is worse.

Enumeration runs in O(n) time for both.

To answer your question, I think 2 and 3 are both viable options. Which one is best depends on the ration of insertions/lookups/enumerations you will get.

For instance, if you do one billion lookups per enumeration, then using `Dictionary` will probably pay off. If instead enumeration happens more often, a sorted array might be better in the end, because the data in the `Dictionary` will first have to be sorted and algorithms like QuickSort can do that in O(n * log n) time.

I suggest you try both in a typical use scenario for you application and see which one is best.

OR, If memory is not a concern, why not use a `Dictionary` AND a sorted array? If this is done properly, you could get the best of both worlds.

Comment: Excellent point about excluding `SortedDictionary` as compared to using an array. I was wondering if I could implement my own collection which behaves as an `OrderedDictionary`. All the same, given I only have around a 100 items, is it worth the effort?

Comment: Probably not, but if you want to try something simple just wrap a dictionary and an array together.

Comment: What I understand by wrapping a dictionary and array together is that: Direct lookups are forwarded to the dictionary, and enumeration is done by iterating the array and looking up the corresponding elements. Also, on inserting every key is added to the array as well as the dictionary, to keep it in its natural order (sequence). Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that is what I had in mind. Of course, when refreshing, you will have to populate both the array and the dictionary, but it seems that's not the most frequent operation so it should be alright.